# Adding a property filter to cypher query explodes memory, why?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a query that explores a DAG-type graph (a bill of materials) for all construction paths leading down to a specific part number (second MATCH), among all the parts associated with a given product (first MATCH). There is a strange behavior I don't understand:

This query runs in a reasonable time using Neo4j community edition (~2 s):

```
WITH '12345' as snid, 'ABCDE' as pid
MATCH (m:Product {full_sn:snid})-[:uses]->(p:Part)
WITH snid, pid, collect(p) AS mparts
MATCH path=(anc:Part)-[:has*]->(child:Part)
WHERE ALL(node IN nodes(path) WHERE node IN mparts)
WITH snid, path, relationships(path)[-1] AS rel, 
nodes(path)[-2] AS parent, nodes(path)[-1] AS child
RETURN stuff I want
```

However, to get the query I want, I must add a filter on the child using the part number pid in the second MATCH statement:

```
MATCH path=(anc:Part)-[:has*]->(child:Part {pn:pid})
```

And when I try to run the new query, neo4j browser compains that there is not enough memory. (Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError). When I run it with EXPLAIN, the db hits are exploding into the 10s of billions, as if I'm asking it for a massive cartestian product: but all I have done is added a restriction on the child, so this should be reducing the search space, shouldn't it?

I also tried adding an index on :Part(pn). Now the profile shown by EXPLAIN looks very efficient, but I still have the same memory error.

If anyone can help me understand why this change between the two queries is causing problems, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Best wishes,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH path=(anc:Part)-[:has*]->(child:Part)
```

The * is exploding to every downstream child node. 
That's appropriate if that is what's desired. If you make this an optional match and limit to the collect items, this should restrict the return results.

```
   OPTIONAL MATCH path=(anc:Part)-[:has*]->(child:Part)
```

This is conceptionally (& crudely) similar to an inner join in SQL.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. The * is intentional. My problem is really to understand why the memory requirements of the query increase when I add a restriction on the pattern.